# Connecting to MySQL over https

Tags: mysql, ssl, https

I have Mysql on a separate server. Do SSL certificates need to be installed on this server as well?  I am currently gettings errors over https.

Please advise..

Thanks

Comment: Voting to move to [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com), although even there you will need to provide more detail.

Comment: Whether you should enable SSL/TLS between your web server and the database server has also been discussed here: http://security.stackexchange.com/q/14334/2435

Comment: Thanks, but I figured it out.  Had to just modify httpd.conf

Answer (score 0):

Modified httpd.conf and it worked fine.  Nothing needed to connect to mysql since the connection is on a private network.